# Need search should happen from server side using dataTable plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search, datatable

I am using [DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) plugin. Currently , search is happening from data available in list. I need to fetch the data from server side on entering value in search box and display in the list. Kindly suggest me the appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built into DataTables. Look at the example here:
https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

From the above link:

> With server-side processing enabled, all paging, searching, ordering
>   actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server where an
>   SQL engine (or similar) can perform these actions on the large data
>   set (after all, that's what the database engine is designed for!). As
>   such, each draw of the table will result in a new Ajax request being
>   made to get the required data.

Initialize with serverSide set and the path to the ajax data endpoint that it should call

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
} );
```

The server side code you write will then take the parameters, search the DB appropriately, and then respond with JSON encoded results for DataTables to consume and use to redraw the table

Comment: Thanq.. It was working fine. But I also need for serverside code on scroll functionality. It should fetch a limited records from server on every scroll.